# Image.Source property (via BitmapImage) lockes the file

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image, file, locking

i want to set the image.source property in my code, like this:

```
Dim bi as new BitmapImage

bi.BeginInit()
bi.UriSource = new Uri("C:/test.png", uriKind.relativeOrAbsolute)
bi.EndInit()

img.Source = bi
```

Thats working, but the problem is that this locked the file and makes me unable to replace the file.

Now my question: Is there any other method to set the image.source property, so that i can say something like file.close() after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad to your BitmapImage:

```
Dim bi as new BitmapImage

bi.BeginInit()
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.UriSource = new Uri("C:/test.png", uriKind.relativeOrAbsolute)
bi.EndInit()

img.Source = bi
```

Or you may read image file contents to the buffer in memory and then use MemoryStream as a StreamSource for the BitmapImage:

```
var imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/test.png")
var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
var bi = new BitmapImage();

bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = stream;
bi.EndInit();
```

Comment: bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
Thats working. Thanks!